# how to say a kanji is ON-yomi ONLY

Tags: kanji

how best to say that a kanji such as 句 has ONLY 音読み , i.e., there is NO kun-yomi.

読みは音読みのみ

??

I want to tag posts at https://www.facebook.com/kanjirecog to indicate this without using romaji or English ... is のみ the best way to say ONLY here ?

Comment: "BUT only" would be clearer ?

Comment: In what sense are you suggesting that 句 does not have a kun'yomi? If you are referring to prescriptive government (and hence school) charts, then yes. However, descriptively, it is easy enough to find kun'yomi in actual texts. For 句, it can be read as a verb magar-u or todomar-u. For magar-u, look in the 1386 text 法華経音訓, page 73 column 5 where you will find 句 glossed with the reading マカル. Historically voicing was often not indicated. In modern spelling, this would be 曲がる. (Out of space, so to be continued.)

Comment: [Continued] If you are familiar with kanji, you may recognize this reading / sense as appropriate for 勾, for which both 句 and 勾 ultimately derive from the same character. I keep running out of space, so I'll leave todomar-u as an exercise for you.

Comment: I only mean to say that a kanji X is has no kun-yomu listed in Book Y ( Henshall, Heisig, Kodansha dict. Z, etc.

In some settings, attacking the example can miss the question !

Answer (score 5):

Native speaker here (if that means anything).

「読みは音読みのみ」 is surely grammatical and it conveys perfectly what needs to be said.  However, it might sound a little awkward to some people with three み's (and two 読み's) in such a short phrase.  「のみ」 itself is a very good word choice even though it is adding another み and this is clearly no place for the informal 「だけ」.

I am going to say that you could keep it as is.  It is not as though one would need to say 「読みは音読みのみ」 three times in a row in one breath.

Other suggestions:

「訓読みはありません。」

「音読みのみ（です）。」

Comment: 「読みは音読みのみ」 Reminds me of when I got to have lunch with the president of 大東文化 along with the rest of the exchange students at the time.  During introductions I described my school (located in the middle of West Virginia) as 中々田舎【なかなかいなか】.  Suffice to say, the pun was not duly appreciated by my audience.  hehehe...